# Почему не работает проверка строки на количество символов

Tags: php

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mb_strlen' (T_STRING) in W:\domains\kinomoon\mail.php on line 11*

```
if (mb_strlen($name)<5  mb_strlen($name)>90)
    {
        header('location: /error/index.html');
    exit;
    }
  else if (mb_strlen($email)<3  mb_strlen($email)>50)
    {
        header('location: /error/index.html');
    exit;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы забыли в условие добавить `||` (или) или `&&` (и)

```
if (mb_strlen($name)<5 || mb_strlen($name)>90)
{
    header('location: /error/index.html');
    exit;
}
else if (mb_strlen($email)<3 || mb_strlen($email)>50)
{
    header('location: /error/index.html');
    exit;
};
```